# Proving $\cos\frac{9}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{7}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{5}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{3}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{1}{11}\pi = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Why is:

$$\cos\frac{9}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{7}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{5}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{3}{11}\pi + \cos\frac{1}{11}\pi = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: $\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$

Comment: Put $11$ points equally spaced around the unit circle, and the average $x$-coordinate should be $0$.